# How to have multiple NPM users set up locally?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using two NPM accounts: a public one and a private one. How would I set it up so that I don't need to `npm login` every time I publish a module on a different account?

UPD: Looking for an NPM inbuilt solution, so no shell scripts or the like

Comment: You could set up a small shell script to switch accounts

Comment: Sure I could. We can script the entire world. ☺ I'll update my question. Thanks

Comment: Linux to the rescue!

Comment: Don't know if it also works for `_authToken` , but you can have a per-project .npmrc: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc

Comment: Just discovered this: https://github.com/perry-mitchell/npm-user-switch

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is how I'm solving it having 4 different NPM logins.

1. In each project's `.gitignore` (and `.npmignore` for NPM modules) add this line: `.npmrc`. This will make sure you never commit (or publish) the `.npmrc` file.
2. In each project's folder create `.npmrc` file containing this: `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111`  (replace the GUID with an actual NPM auth token, e.g. you can grab it from `~/.npmrc`)

The `npm` CLI will look in your current folder for the `.npmrc` file (or in any **parent** folder) and will use it for auth.

As the result all `npm` commands work as is, no need to pass `--userconfig` or anything.

---

In addition to the above you can have the **default** NPM token across your computer/laptop.

1. Make sure `.npmrc` is NOT present in `.gitignore` (which is common for most projects out there).
2. Create the `.npmrc` file in the root folder of your project. Put this inside: `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}`. This will make `npm` to use `NPM_TOKEN` env. var. And `npm` will abort if such env. var. is not found.
3. Commit and push that file. (Yes. Seriously.)
4. Make sure your shell has the `NPM_TOKEN` environment variable set. E.g. `NPM_TOKEN=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111`. I have it in my `~/.bash_profile`.

All the projects, which have this file committed, will use your environment variable `NPM_TOKEN` for npm auth.

As the result all npm commands work as is, no need to pass `--userconfig` or anything.

This is good and secure enough for CI (Continuous Integration). All CI-s allow you to set environment variables. Using this approach you can change the NPM user with a simple env. var. change.

---

**Pro Tip**

Type `npm whoami` command to check which token is currently being used in the folder.

Comment: this is a great solution and works in 2019. allows to specify per-package npm usernam

Comment: Sadly my team needs .npmrc in source control.

Comment: @JohnXiao then use the second approach.

Answer (score 18):

I know I'm a bit late (okay, super late) in answering this, but I've just come across the same issue whilst having to publish to both private and public registries in quick succession.

> The best solution I found to this issue is by having a second or third configuration file at the user level. This is how my `$HOME` directory looks at the moment:

`Admins-iMac% ls -la ~/.npmrc*
-rw-------  1 moi  staff   52 10 Apr 14:48 /Users/moi/.npmrc
-rw-r--r--  1 moi  staff  498 10 Apr 14:52 /Users/moi/.npmrc-private-reg
-rw-r--r--  1 moi  staff   70 10 Apr 14:48 /Users/moi/.npmrc-public-reg`

In the "private" and "public" dotfiles I have Artifactory and npmjs.org user setups respectively, but aside from that they're empty. My default NPM configuration file also has very little inside it, as most of my configuration sits in a global file, the reasons behind that are beside the point for this question though...

> When it comes to me publishing a module to either registry, I simply pass the `--userconfig` option with the path to the file that I wish to authenticate with.

For example, I just pushed a package to the public NPM registry with ease, like this:

`npm publish --userconfig ~/.npmrc-public-reg`

---

- npm-config: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#npmrc-files

Comment: Can you write an example content for your `.npmrc`s? Same as above like `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${MY_NPM_TOKEN}` just with different tokens?