# How to npm login as a different user per scope on same registry?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, .npmrc

I need to set up multiple npm authTokens that are for two different scopes, but both scopes are on the same registry.

```
@scope1:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@scope2:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

I have tried to add the an authToken to each scope like this:

```
@scope1:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${TOKEN_1}
@scope2:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${TOKEN_2}
```

But I get a `405` error when I try to install a package.

I tried reading [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config), but I cannot find a way to specify different tokens for different scopes on the same registry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have multiple NPM users set up locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114166/how-to-have-multiple-npm-users-set-up-locally)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the accepted answer is using multiple projects/folders.
I am looking for a solution that works in the same folder/same .npmrc file

Comment: Was a workaround ever found for this?

Answer (score 11):

I contacted the npm support and got the following response:

> Users cannot mix-and-match auth for a single registry. We recommend having a single npm user that's granted access to all of the packages and to use the token for that user.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of a hacky answer - but it works. At least on github packages where I am using it.  I assume it works on npmjs.org but I don't have any private packages there to test.

```rc
@scope1:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=TOKEN1

@scope2:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com:443
//npm.pkg.github.com:443/:_authToken=TOKEN2

@scope3:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com:0443
//npm.pkg.github.com:0443/:_authToken=TOKEN3
```

Basically, just make them different registries by specifying a port even though it is the same port.

Comment: Seems like it's not working anymore. It'll always use the last defined token.

Comment: It doesn't work in node v16.19.0 (npm v8.19.3), but it works in node v14.17.3 (npm v6.14.13) and before. Maybe NPM treated a bug and fixed?

Comment: Use npmjs mirrors for this purpose: `registry.npmjs.cf`